# Is it right to have three column and three of them are primary key in mysq table

Tags: mysql

Someone created this table 'customer_address', which is a mapping table and it has only 3 columns which are id_customer,id_parent,id_address and the three of them are primary key, is it right??? and i am facing a problem that when i insert rows at a point while inserting a new row a existing row deletes / replaces automatically,Suggest me what to do

Comment: Its not right. I think each of this columns should be foreign key.

Comment: they say this as composite primary key :(

Comment: You are describing this rather poorly. See **Section2 / What does Show your Schema Mean?** of [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38899465) to help us to help you :p